# Stylesheet only for ipad device

Tags: css, local.xml

is there if param only for iOS devices? like it have for IE

```
<params/>
<if>IE 7</if>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a post over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

In which they cover this topic, specifying an OS like the iOS only is not possible as far as I am aware, but you can target the max-width of a device, for instance, iPhone, tablet etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Theme for iPad if you want to:
SYSTEM > CONFIG > DESIGN > THEMES > Type = iPad

Comment: This completely misses the question being asked. I suggest you delete this, re-read the question, and post a different answer.